# Hide last div in a page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to hide last div from my web page.

```
("div").eq(-1).hide();
```

Can I have the  code for working

Thanks in advance, Vicky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not referencing [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) at all:

```
  $("div").eq(-1).hide();
//^-- missing the $ for jQuery
```

You can also use a more semantic approach:

```
$("div:last").hide();
```

[Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/sS7pD/) [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/sS7pD/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Fabrício Matté, Sorry, will go through thoroughly :)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$("div:last").hide();
```

or

```
$("div").last().hide();
```

I didn't know `eq` took negative indexes so your only problem is that you were missing the `$`/`jQuery` before your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the missing `$` at the start of the line.

But you can also use `last`, which I think is more readable. It's as easy as:

```
$("div").last().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
$("div").last().hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

First reference jQuery. Add the code inside `$(document).ready()`.
A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is ready. jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").eq(-1).hide();
});
```